# Jenkins plugins dependencies version

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins that defines a dependencie of the plugin:
github-oauth:0.33 (https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-oauth/)

According to its github, it depends on https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-branch-source plugin.
We can confirm that in this: https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-oauth-plugin/blob/master/pom.xml#L123

```
2020-07-22 17:40:11.505+0000 [id=25]    SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed Loading plugin GitHub Authentication plugin v0.33 (github-oauth)
java.io.IOException: Failed to load: GitHub Authentication plugin (0.33)
 - Failed to load: GitHub Branch Source Plugin (2.8.3)
```

Why it is trying to use 2.8.3 version?
The main problem was that 2.8.3 depends on github 1.31.0, but I defined 1.30.0.
When I updated it the problem was solved.
Also, looking on the dependencies page:

[image]

Why it shows ">"?

Answer (score 0):

It means what required plugin's version could be higher version.

Comment: Can you provide some information on this? Jenkins documentation or something, because it that is true its possible that I will have more problems on future, also not pinning version usually is a bad practice

Comment: So your question was "Why it shows ">"?" - it shows you lowest possible versions of required plugins. It could be higher. With new version of installed plugin versions of required plugins could become also higher. Is it clear or you need additional info?

Comment: Stil not clear, I need some oficial documentation of that behavior. Why is it the lowest possible since it is pinned, it is a really strange behavior.